# Валидация regExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, валидация

Просьба помочь сделать валидацию поиска. что у меня : символы которые я хочу отсеиваются,НО если первоначально ввести пробел - то выскакивает ошибка.Что я хочу получить : 2-3 слова в поиске и чтобы не ругался на пробел.либо подсказку как это сделать?

```
[var input = document.getElementById("input");
var bab_number = document.querySelector(".header_form_search_error");
var pattern = /^\s*[a-z0-9-а-яё]+(?:\s+[a-z0-9-а-яё]+){1,2}\s*$/i;
var value;

input.addEventListener("input", search_error);

function search_error(value) {
  var newValye = this.value;
  if (pattern.test(newValye)) {
    bab_number.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    bab_number.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

]
[ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/RedSkyby/pen/JeWgXQ)

Comment: Советую заменить на `var pattern = /^\s*(?:[a-z0-9-а-яё]+(?:\s+[a-z0-9-а-яё]+){0,2}\s*)?$/i;`. Тот, что вы приняли, не следует "лучшим практикам".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так подходит?

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var pattern = /^\s{0,1}([a-z0-9-а-яё]{1,}\s*){0,3}$/i;

input.addEventListener("input", search_error);

function search_error(event) {
  var newValye = event.target.value;
  console.log(pattern.test(newValye))
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="input" >
```

Comment: а как придумать чтобы первоначально на пробел не ругался?? а так ваш ответ верный) спасибо.

Comment: подправил, не ругается на 1 пробел. Если надо больше - с первым `\s` поколдуйте

Comment: Большое спасибо,